# how to activate a submit button from the jquery section

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a form that I want to run its submit button from the jquery section
is there a way that would allow me to run it form there even though I did not click on it

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and show examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `$("form").submit()`